# Switch case value with binary value?

Tags: c

I'm doing a switch case where the case values need to be in binary digits like `01,010,0100,0,00,000,` and so on.

```
switch(Code)
{
          case 0:
               {
                   printf("A");
                   break;
                   }
          case 00:
               {
                   printf("B");
                   break;
                   }
          case 000:
               {
                   printf("C");
                   break;
}
```

I know that if I input 000, it it will be stored as 0. My question is how do you input 000 so that I can get `printf("C")`

Comment: You're missing a closing `}`.

Comment: The values `0`, `00` and `000` all are binary for 0 so there is no way around. (Also note, that in fact those are octal values in the program, because they all start with 0).

Comment: You haven't mentioned how you're receiving the input. I'm assuming it's user input. Store that in a string. Change your `switch - case` to an `if - else if` construct and use `strcmp` to compare strings.

Comment: How can you differentiate `0` from `000`, even in binary?

Comment: 0, 00, 000 are all zeros - same values. if the amount of zeroes matters you should use strings

Comment: Zero it zero. It doesn't matter how many zeros there are, they're all equal to zero. If you want to store multiple zeros, you need to store them as a string. Your question therefore is unanswerable, as the only response to "How can I do this?" is "You can't".

Answer (score 3):

I can't imagine why you would want to distinguish between these numbers, as in any representation they are the same number, but I guess you will have to examine them as strings. 
You can't put strings into a switch statement in C, so you will just have to have a sequence of if/else statements:

```
void selectString(char *input)
{
    if(strcmp(input, "0") == 0)
    {
        printf("A");
    }
    else if(strcmp(input, "00") == 0)
    {
        printf("B");
    }
    else if(strcmp(input, "000") == 0)
    {
        printf("C");
    }
}
```

Having said this, what you are asking appears very much like an **XY problem**, that is, you are asking how to do weird thing Y because you think you need to do it to solve X. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The question states specifically to use a switch case. It wants to convert morse code(zeros instead of commas) to letters.

Comment: So it is an XY problem. If you want a switch, you have to parse the input into a form amenable to that. In what form are you getting your input?

Comment: It is user input. Based on table of values, the corresponding letters for each morse code is to be found

Comment: I meant "what symbols are used", is it 0 for dot, 1 for dash?

Comment: So your problem is in the encoding.  Morse code is short and long beeps representing 0's and 1's.  But you don't know when a value starts.  I would recommend prefixing each series of input with a 1 start bit.  Then your values are 10, 100, and 1000.  You can easily compare these in binary representation.

Comment: Yeah dot for 0 and 1 for dash. If I do prefix, how would I prefix 000?

Comment: you would prefix 000 as 1000.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you have a series of bits that you are trying to decode (signal on the wire).  But you don't know when your packet of information starts.  What you are missing in the encoding is the start of a letter.  (You also don't have start of word, I'd recommend making up an unused number to represent a space between words).

In your program would recommend prefixing each series of bits with a 1 start bit (note this is not actually transmitted but implied because of the time duration of nothing being transmitted). Then your values are 10, 100, and 1000. You can easily compare these in binary representation.  Note the smallest valid series of bits is then the letter 'e' which would be 10 in binary.  A single 1 bit is not a valid value.  Just from glancing at the [Morse code entry here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code) it would appear that the alphabet forms a numbering system that could be stored in a lookup table for a fast implementation.

Comment: Could you give me an example on how to do so? Thank you

Comment: I don't know how you are getting input into your program, so it is hard to suggest anything specific.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: unsigned int Code;
printf("Please Enter Morse Code:");
scanf("%o", &Code);
switch(Code)

Comment: int value = 1;  while(int c = getc()) { value <<= 1; if (c == '1') value += 1;}

Comment: The above code will initialize the start bit.  Read in characters one at a time.  For each character left-shift the start bit.  If the read character is a '1' (i.e. ASCII '1' character) then add one.  This is super simplistic, and may need adjustments, but is shows how to initialize your value with a start bit, then read in data 'from the wire'.  In a real-world situation you would probably add a parity bit to the end. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit

Answer (score 0):

Given you're using this for Morse (I'm guessing 0 = Dot, 1 = dash) in your variable.
"Code" Must be a String.

```
switch(Code)
{
    case "01":   //".-"
        printf("A");
        break;
    case "100":   //"-.."
        printf("B");
        break;
    case "0001":   //"...-"
        printf("V");
    break;
}
```